# Pass array to Laravel route via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel

I have laravel route defined as below

```
Route::get('dos',array('as'=>'saveOrder','uses'=>'HomeController@SaveOrder'));
```

And my ajax request as below

```
var params = $("#tab_logic :input[name='id[]']").serialize();
//alert(params);

$.ajax({
    url: "dos",
    method: 'GET',
    data: params,
    //dataType:"json",
    success: function( data ) 
    {
        // do nothing
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

I get an 500 server error when executed. The input field ID[] is an array and I want this array to be sent to laravel route so that I can handle it in controller action with Input::get('id').

Comment: Did you try using the complete url in ajax? like `http://domain/dos` Though 500 error shouldn't be caused by this, yet give it a try.

Comment: Check `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` for errors

Comment: Gotcha, there was error in scope query

Answer (score 0):

by checking the log found out that there was issue in scope query.How do I acheive this using scope query.

```
$data = Books::select(DB::raw('count(*) as order_count, subject'))
                ->whereIn('id',$id)
                ->groupBy('subject')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a 50 rep. so I can't comment.
Try puttying fowardslash before "dos" in your ajax container

```
$("#tab_logic :input[name='id[]']").serialize();
//alert(params);

$.ajax({
    url: "/dos", //<- this line is edited
    method: 'GET',
    data: params,
    //dataType:"json",
    success: function( data ) 
    {
        // do nothing
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::get('dos','HomeController@DOS');

var params = $("#tab_logic :input[name='id[]']").serialize();
//alert(params);

$.ajax({
    url: "dos",
    method: 'GET',
    data: params,
    //dataType:"json",
    success: function( data ) 
    {
        // do nothing
        alert(data);
    }
});

//Controller
 public function DOS()
    {
 $data= Input::all();

}
```